# my JavaScript function is not running in my php code

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to run a javascript function inside my PHP code but the javascript function is not calling, or not working, but when I try to run it without the PHP it works fine:

```
<div class="chatbox">
    <div class="chatbox_head">chat</div>
    <div class="chatbox_body">
    <?php 
    $n = 'Ozoibekwe';
    $m = 'joy';
    echo '
        <div class="sidebar-name">
            <!-- Pass username and display name to register popup -->
            <a href="javascript:register_popup('.$n.', '.$m.');">
                <img width="30" height="30" src="user_pix/david.jpg" />
                <span>Ozoibekwe joy</span>
            </a>
        </div><br> ';
    ?>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: You probably want quotes around `$n` and `$m`. Of course, your code is a bad practice anyways.

Comment: Please don't vandalise your question @ELOIKEDAVID

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to quote the strings in your javascript function:

`javascript:register_popup(\''.$n.'\', \''.$m.'\');`:

```
<div class="chatbox">
    <div class="chatbox_head">chat</div>
    <div class="chatbox_body">
        <?php 
        $n = 'Ozoibekwe';
        $m = 'joy';
        echo '
             <div class="sidebar-name">
                <!-- Pass username and display name to register popup -->
                <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="register_popup(\''.$n.'\', \''.$m.'\');">
                    <img width="30" height="30" src="user_pix/david.jpg" />
                    <span>Ozoibekwe joy</span>
                </a>
            </div><br> ';
        ?>          
    </div>  
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could do it like this, which is much cleaner:

```
<?php 
$n = 'Ozoibekwe';
$m = 'joy';
?>
<div class="chatbox">
    <div class="chatbox_head">chat</div>
    <div class="chatbox_body">
        <div class="sidebar-name">
            <!-- Pass username and display name to register popup -->
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="register_popup('<?= $n ?>', '<?= $m ?>');">
                <img width="30" height="30" src="user_pix/david.jpg" />
                <span>Ozoibekwe joy</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <br>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: i tried that but its not working, i cannot call the javascript function

Comment: @ELOIKEDAVID See edit, changed to onClick event, try that.